# Passing variables from page to page

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another using `$_GET`, and I can't seem to get it to work. I would appreciate any help.

First I create a link based on the results from the database here.

**clients.php**

```
require_once("../auth/config.class.php");
require_once("../auth/auth.class.php");
$config = new Config;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$config->dbhost};dbname={$config->dbname}", $config->dbuser,     $config->dbpass);
$auth = new Auth($dbh, $config);

$uid = $auth->SessionUID($_COOKIE['authID']);       


        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fname, lname, id FROM client WHERE uid=? ORDER by id");
        $query->execute(array($uid));
        $rslt = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($rslt as $row ){

                echo "<a href=../pages/status.php?id=$row[id]>$row[fname]<br></a>";

        }
```

The result from the link are listed on this page

**status.php**

```
$cid = $_GET['id'];  



    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT function FROM funcbathing WHERE cid=?");
        $query->execute(array($cid));
        $rslt = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (empty($rslt)){

        header('Location: ../views/careplan.php');
        echo $cid

        }
        else{
            header('Location: ../views/home.php');
        }
```

I would like to pass the `$cid` to this page in a text box, but I can't seem to get it work. Here's the page that the id should get passed to.

**careplan.php** this is a bigger form but I removed the irrelevant information for simplicity.

```
        <input type="text" name="clientid" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['cid'])) { echo $_GET['cid']; } ?>"  />
```

Comment: you'd have to include your IDs in your `Location` redirects as well, e.g. `Location: ../views/careplan.php?id=$foo`

Comment: Thanks I changed it to `header('Location: ../views/careplan.php?cid='.$cid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Location: ../views/careplan.php?cid='.$cid);
```

EDIT:
You should learn to print the strings in a valid manor, check error_reporting(E_ALL); and display_errors=on with your string.

then try this:

```
echo '<a href="../pages/status.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'.$row["fname"].'<br></a>';
```

or:

```
echo sprintf('<a href="../pages/status.php?id=%s">%s<br></a>', $row['id'], $row['fname']);
```

or even:

```
echo "<a href=\"../pages/status.php?id={$row["id"]}\">{$row["fname"]}<br></a>";
```

or any of the other hundreds way to write a valid string

Comment: Please use `htmlspecialchars` on those things. Otherwise somebody will have enter a name like `<script>window.alert('Oops');</script>`.

Comment: `filter_var` would be better. but in this case he is getting the values from the db, if he took care of the strings while insert its not a problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, the strings are valid I just had to change the header. Thanks

Comment: interesting, there should be an undefined constant notice.